# Emacs Jedi unable to complete jedi:install-server

Tags: python, linux, emacs, archlinux, jedi

I'm fairly new to Python and Emacs and was trying to setup the jedi plugin using MELP. It seems to be struggling with sexpdata when it runs pip. I think the problem might originate from sexpdata. I tried installing it within the pip that jedi sets up and it gave an error while setting up wheel. I was, however able to install it on a venv, but unsure how to make jedi use that one or if that would fix it. I use endeavourOS and was able to install it no problem on a macbook I have. I tried deleting the ~/.emacs/elpa/jedi* folders and reinstalling the plugin to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Running jedi:install:server

```
Running: pip install --upgrade /home/name/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20210503.1315/...Done
deferred error : (error "Deferred process exited abnormally:
  command: /home/name/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/pip
  exit status: exit 1
  event: exited abnormally with code 1

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Error from pip sexpdata:

```
Collecting sexpdata>=0.0.3 (from epc>=0.0.4->jediepcserver==0.3.0)
  Using cached sexpdata-1.0.1.tar.gz (8.6 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... [?25l- \\\\ | / - done
[?25h  Getting requirements to build wheel ... [?25l- error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [78 lines of output]
```

Another error:

```
        File \\\"/tmp/pip-build-env-fhs0pp5v/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py\\\", line 183, in _license
          _set_config(dist, \\\"license\\\", val[\\\"text\\\"])
                                       ~~~^^^^^^^^
      KeyError: 'text'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you do **not** have an active virtualenv:

   ```bash
   $ deactivate
   ```
2. Install your distribution's *python3-sexpdata* package

   ```bash
   $ sudo apt install python3-sexpdata
   ```
3. Try `jedi:install-server` again inside emacs. Alternatively you can run the command to setup jedi directly in the shell:

   ```
   $ pip install --upgrade $HOME/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20210503.1315/
   ```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I'm on arch and the sexpdata in aur is deprecated and won't install. I was able to update it with the Python I had compiled in the /opt folder (python3.12). The pacman python won't let me use pip or even change the link for python. Is there a way to make emacs/jedi use that python when it runs jedi:install-server? Sorry I'm still learning.